# Исключение типа "Не удается найти указанный файл"

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

```
string[] allFoundFiles;
    string substr = "C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Accessories\\";
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        allFoundFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Accessories", "*.lnk", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string a in allFoundFiles)
        {
            int n = a.IndexOf(substr);
            string add_str = a.Remove(n, substr.Length);
            run_program.Items.Add(add_str);
        }
    }
private void run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        foreach (string a in allFoundFiles)
        {
            if (substr+run_program.Text ==  a)
            {
                Process.Start(a);
            }
        }
    }
```

Cчитываю все ярлыки стандартных программ из указанного пути. Добавляю в comboBox их сокращенные названия (без пути). Потом при нажатии кнопки, запускается выбранная программа. Проблема в том, что бОльшая часть приложений запускается, а  на некоторые срабатывает исключение "Не удается найти указанный файл". Хотя эти приложения находятся там же, где и остальные, которые запускаются. Не могу понять, в чем проблема, путь при запуске указывается верный.

Comment: Вы не могли бы упростить пример? Совершенно точно то, что ваш код разделён на две функции, а вопросу не имеет отношения. Да и весь цикл тоже. Покажите, с каким конкретно `a` процесс не стартует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том что вы используете сборку `Any CPU` или `x86` при сборке `x64` все программы находит.